Issue with Behavior Switching and Message Delivery to Child Actors in Akka Delivery
we are migrating from AtLeastOnceDelivery to Akka's new delivery mechanism. I followed the documentation and implemented the logic accordingly, but I’m encountering an issue when processing a message that has its own logic and then needs to be delivered to a child actor.
My main producer actor has several child actors, each with its own producer controller. I have stored references to these producer controllers in the producer actor. When I want to deliver a message to one of these producer controllers, an error occurs if the producer controller hasn't sent a Request.Next message to the producer before I try to send the message.
The documentation suggests using behavior switching and stashing, so I switched the actor's behavior to WaitForRequestNext. However, this causes all other producer actors that are able to process messages to become idle, waiting for a Request.Next message that isn’t intended for them.
Is there a solution to this issue, or am I misunderstanding something about the behavior switching and delivery process?
